# No se actualiza base datos sql excepto el ID

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion en dot net maui y tengo una base datos que quiero insertar datos de un entry al cambiar en el query ID si lo inserte pero al nombrar culquier otra columna no lo hace

```
con.Open();
    string insertQuery = "INSERT Principal (Time) VALUES (@Time)"; 
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con);
           
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", result);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Info.Text = "Paso";
con.Close();
```

y este es codigo de la base datos

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Principal] (
    [Id]      INT        NOT NULL,
    [Circuit] NCHAR (10) NULL,
    [State]   INT        NULL,
    [Time]    INT        NULL,
    [Order]   INT        NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

si cambio el Time por Id en el codigo C# si lo inserta

Answer (score 0):

La clausula INSERT es INSERT INTO. por lo que veo, el dato que debe ir en Time es una variable que se llama resultado. Tienes que ver que la variable resultado sea de tipo int. Si es de tipo Date no va a funcionar, por eso al pasar ID sí funciona, porque seguramente ID sea un int.
O prueba colocarle como nombre en la table iTime (haciendo referencia con la i que es de tipo integer) y así evitas que entre en conflicto con algun nombre reservado del sistema. Ya que Time suele ser un nombre reservado.

Comment: La variable resultado es de tipo entero también intente hacer esto buscando el error de por que no se actualiza otra variables   ` string insertQuery = "UPDATE Principal SET Time = 30, Order = 1 WHERE Id = 1"  `

Answer (score 0):

ya logre resolverlo utilando otra manera de actualizar la base de datos utilizando el id para poder estos cambios, en vez de llamar a otro parametro llame al id para que en caso en que se encontrara actulizara los datos

string insertQuery = "UPDATE

```
Principal  " +
"SET Time = CASE " +
"WHEN Id = 0 THEN 8 " +
"WHEN Id = 1 THEN 7  " +
"WHEN Id = 2 THEN 6 " +
"WHEN Id = 3 THEN 5 " +
"ELSE Time " +
"END," +
"Secuences = CASE " +
"WHEN Id = 0 THEN 4 " +
"WHEN Id = 1 THEN 3 " +
"WHEN Id = 2 THEN 2 " +
"WHEN Id = 3 THEN 1 " +
"ELSE Secuences " +
 "END;";
```